# Google Form Get Last responses

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I can't understand why Google Form is returning me not the last responses, but the penultimate one after I run an OnSubmit script. Let me explain better, I intend to intercept the user's responses and when sending the form to propose a link pre-filled with his last answers given that he can modify and postpone.

```
  function getLastFormResponse(form = FormApp.getActiveForm()) {
 
 
  form.getResponses()              
    .pop()                         
    .getItemResponses()            
    .forEach((itemResponse) => {   
      this[itemResponse.getItem().getTitle()] = itemResponse.getResponse(); 

    }
    
    );
}
const formResponse = new getLastFormResponse();

const name = formResponse['NAME'];
Logger.log(name);
const surname = formResponse['SURNAME'];
Logger.log(surname);
const age = formResponse['AGE'];
Logger.log(age);
const reserved_room = formResponse['RESERVED_ROOM'];
Logger.log(reservedRoom);

var constructionLink = ('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScgu1FWB6-tQjpviyr9_dZetd2SKdqZZmsL_Imp30nWYqsq7g/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.81904614='+name+'&entry.1534059913='+surname+'&entry.181893772='+age+'&entry.772338055='+reservedRoom);
Logger.log(constructionLink);
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(formResponse,null,2));

form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
form.setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for your feedback !!'+ constructionLink )
```

So, when the user press Submit button, a link comes out pre-filled with the "latest" information present... but, in reality, not the last (before the submit) but the penultimate ones are taken from corresponding spreadsheet ...

I would like to get the latest that he filled out.

Comment: I have some question, you want to get last response from the form, or the last question that user has submitted? and do you want to show the custom confirmation message to the same user who just submitted the form?

Comment: I would like the last responses (more exactly I would like the current response that the user is submitting at that moment). And then generate a pre-filled link consisting of the latest responses.

Comment: The code that I wrote you works fine, but it does not take the last responses (that the user is submitting), but the previous one, I assume that the getItemResponses() method fetches the last response belonging to that form, which is not still the one that the user is submitting ... evidently at that moment it is not yet written on the spreadsheet (this is my hypothesis)

Comment: Yes that's a normal behavior, you can't update the form on run-time, so when user submits the form, he/she will only see the second last response, and form submits than the latest response updates.

Comment: Ok, and how can i get the latest responses? via an HTML code?

Comment: You can't redirect the user to any url after form submission, what you can do is adding the webapp url which only shows latest response. that way when user open the url he/she will be able to what has been submitted

Comment: I cannot understand your showing script. How is your script run?